Can we use time difference as the condition to classify control and experimental group
I came across a 'study' where the 'researcher' wanted to find out whether certain personality traits (for example, conscientiousness) would influence the number of car accidents that a person might have.
To answer the question, the 'researcher' used participants of the general population as the control group and the experimental group consisted of participants who had car accidents during the data collection period. They then used independent t-test to compare whether the average personality score between the two group was significant different.
My questions then:

Is it valid to use time difference to classify those participants into control and
experimental groups like that? I thought this 'study' was lack of
the element of condition/treatment because there was nothing
difference to distinguish between two group, except for having a car
accident during the data collection period - a condition that the
'researcher' had no control of.
Were the results obtained from the t-test of this 'research'
valid/meaningful?

